# Wordpress very slow wp-super-cache

Tags: caching, wordpress

I use the plugin wp-super-cache in my wordpress to cache files.
After the cache, the plugin works very well, files are served very fast.

But, at the first access, the wp-super-cache plugin take at least 7 seconds to cache a page (some times more 20 seconds).
It's absolutely horrible to work like this.

When I disable the plugin, each page take 2 or 3 seconds.
I don't understand why this plugin takes so munch time to cache my pages.

Do you have any idea about that ?

Thanks.

Comment: Post your settings, the name of your host, maybe even your domain name so others can go to your site and see why the initial load time is so high?

Comment: Sorry but I can't give you all access about the web site. What settings do you want to know ?

Comment: The cause might be your settings (WP Super Cache, .htaccess, plugins), if you can't share them I can't help you.

Comment: Is this the site? http://blog-dev.net/

Comment: The .htaccess is the default one. I use 11 plugins: sexybookmark, Contact Form 7, All in One SEO Pack, Google XML Sitemaps, Google Analytics for WordPress, FancyBox for WordPress, SI CAPTCHA Anti-Spam, Simple Tags, Simplicy Twitter Press, WordPress.com Stats, WP Super Cache. For wp super cache, I use php mode to cache files

Comment: There are a lot of things you can do. I'll post them as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

Initial page load will always be slower than the second load because WPSC has to generate the cached page the first time.

I would use mod_rewrite instead of PHP mode, if possible. Per WPSC documentation, that is the fastest caching/serving method.

You could also try offloading some requests using the "Use Google Libraries" plugin.

Several of your .js files have a `?ver` parameter which would prevent them from being cached. I remove them from my site using this code, added to functions.php:

```
/* remove query strings from js files, to allow for caching */
add_filter( 'script_loader_src', '_remove_script_version', 15, 1 );
add_filter( 'style_loader_src', '_remove_script_version', 15, 1 );
function _remove_script_version( $src ){
    $parts = explode( '?', $src );
    return $parts[0];
}
```

You may also want to move some Javascript requests to the footer instead of loading them in the header. You can use the "Javascript to footer" plugin, or add this to your functions.php:

```
remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_print_scripts');
remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 1);
remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_print_head_scripts', 9);
add_action('wp_footer', 'wp_print_scripts', 5);
add_action('wp_footer', 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 5);
add_action('wp_footer', 'wp_print_head_scripts', 5);
```

You may also want to consider removing extra links from your header, they are time sinks. More code for functions.php to remove "wlwmanifest" and "generator" meta links from your header:

```
remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_generator');
remove_action('wp_head', 'wlwmanifest_link');
remove_action('wp_head', 'rsd_link');
remove_action('wp_head', 'index_rel_link');
```

Your blog front page also loads tweets -- those external calls can take time. There is also a lot of inline CSS added by your theme. Why is the theme doing that AND using a CSS file?

These are micro-optimizations but together they might save you some loading time.

Comment: Ok, I think you haven't understand my problem. All your advises are browser side. My problem is about server side which take many second to generate cache. The css or js is not manipulate by server. Thanks for your answer ;)

Comment: The first two codeblocks did not work for me. WP 3.4.1. I did not try the third. PHP complained the functions were not valid in the functions.php file.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using hypercache? It's also good if you are low on resources.

For wp super cache, this often happens. You must have had browser cache enabled and therefore it loaded up pretty fast. That is normal actually.

Answer (score 0):

I tried many different caching plugins. They all seem to work fine in the beginning but then they slow your site down to a crawl. W3C and Super Cache are the worst offenders. The problem with all these caching plugins is that they are too convoluted. Too many parts that may and may not work depending on your host and million other factors. You enable one little thing, or set different parameters which you think will speed up your site, but it messes up your site further, and causes conflicts with other plugins. I believe caching should be part of WP core, because all these caching plugins are a disaster.  For example, in Super Cache I set some pages to be cached as static pages, because they are never updated, low and behold, some of these pages load as blank page, others load fine, and some take forever to load.

My site loads so much faster after disabling Super Cache, it actually makes me ask, what do I need a caching plugin for anyways?